# Quick build options in Texmaker

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I'm working with Texmaker 4.1 and Miktex 2.9. 
My document consists of 4 files, 3 section tex-files and 1 main tex-file. When working in the sections it always upsets me that I have to change the view to the main file to get the document build. So my question is if there is a way to configure one of the user defined quick build options in Texmaker so that when hitting the button my main tex-file is build and not the one which is shown.

Thank

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Open your main file and use the *Options* menu to *Define Current Document as 'Master Document'*. See below.

[image]

Comment: @Pete. Welcome. Almost everything here is fast.